# WebStorm and WSL: Failed to prepare environment: Trying to get WSL path from a different WSL distribution

Tags: ubuntu, eslint, webstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I cannot configure WebStorm to work with my projects in WSL (this happened after I reinstalled my Windows OS and WSL). I think that the problem is related to WSL configuration, but I cannot find which exactly.

[image]

The same problem with ESLint in my projects:

[image]

[image]

```
C:\Users\FTowe>wsl --status
Default Distribution: Ubuntu
Default Version: 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 3/6/2022
The Windows Subsystem for Linux kernel can be manually updated with 'wsl --update', but automatic updates cannot occur due to your system settings.
To receive automatic kernel updates, please enable the Windows Update setting: 'Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows'.
For more information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel.

Kernel version: 5.10.16

C:\Users\FTowe>
```

```sh
gt@DESKTOP-8828LLP:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
gt@DESKTOP-8828LLP:~$
```

What is wrong with my WSL distribution and how to fix this problem?

Comment: did you try removing the existing Node wsl interpreter configuration in **Node.js Interpreters** dialog and setting up a new one? If this doesn't help, please create a support ticket and share your idea.log

Comment: I'd encourage you to read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) regarding why we ask that you not post images that can be represented as text and edit your question appropriately.  Thanks!

Comment: [NotTheDr01ds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11810933/notthedr01ds) - Thanks for the advice! I replaced some images. [lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) -  Thank you too, it helped.

Answer (score 4):

So, thanks to [@lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) I found this new `Ubuntu /home/...` version in my **node interpreter** version configuration(the previous selection was `Ubuntu-20.04 /home/...` and then the same path to node).

> did you try removing the existing Node wsl interpreter configuration in Node.js Interpreters

[image]

After I checked another option(`Ubuntu /home/...`), applied, and clicked *OK* everything started working again. But the previous option disappeared when I opened settings again. I checked it a few times in different projects and confused about that.

[image]

As I can remember there was no another option **Ubuntu /home/...** before. So it kind of solved itself? Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

The steps i made for fix

Check nvm is installed with node version and available on the terminal.

Check in your bash profile nvm scripts added as below

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Check is your interpreter set correctly with WSL.

After that re install the webstorm one more time.

Good luck